# Sending information with a Signal in Linux

Tags: c, linux, signals

When sending a signal from one process to another, I also want to send a value of type *long*. Is that possible? I am using SIGUSR1.

Comment: It is possible as cnicutar said, but you should probably find a better channel for communication. Using signals when you don't absolutely have to is usually a very bad idea from a design standpoint.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure you can, but you'll have to send it with [`sigqueue(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigqueue.2.html) instead of `kill(2)`. And you can send an `int` or a `sival_ptr`.

```
union sigval {
    int   sival_int;
    void *sival_ptr;
};
```

**Establish the handler**

```
struct sigaction sa;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; /* Important. */

sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
```

**The handler for a signal established using SA_SIGINFO**

```
static void
handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *ucontext)
{
    si->si_value; /* This is what you're looking for. */
}
```

**Sending an integer**

```
union sigval sv;
sv.sival_int = 42;

sigqueue(pid, SIGUSR1, sv);
```