# Sending a variable changed by a signal to a process created by exec in the child process.[C]

Tags: c, signals, fork, exec

So I'm creating a signal handler to modify the speed at which output is printed to the screen. The output is done by a process that prints to another terminal open while still allowing the user to put in input such as '+' to increase the speed its read and '-' to decrease the speed.

The code looks something like this.

```
static state* start_button(void)
{
    state *destination;                                                        

    pid_t pid;                                                    
    pid = fork();                                                 
    switch(pid)                                                   
    {                                                                          
        case -1:                                   
            destination = &ready;                                              
            break;                                                             
        case 0:                                                                          
            execl("./outputTerminal",
                "outputTerminal",file_number,"/dev/ttys001",NULL);                                                                     
            break;                                                             
        default:                                                               
            destination = &going;                                            
            break;                                                             
    }                                                                          

    return destination;
 }
```

In the going state(`going.c`) my thought process was to create volatile variables seconds and nanoseconds and use those variables to update the `nanosleep()` function that outputTerminal is using to read the lines 1 line at a time like so in the code snippet below. Is this possible? This is a homework question btw. I have all the functions working like they are supposed to I just need to figure out how to send the variables changed by the signal over to that process. I tried doing `kill(baby_pid,SIGUSR1)` in the going state after I set the signal handler because I saved the pid but that just kills the process outputTerminal for some reason.

```
 //going.c
 volatile sig_atomic_t seconds;
 volatile sig_atomic_t nanoseconds; //Update these in the going state

 //Then pass them to the process outputTerminal like so


 //outputTerminal.c
 struct timespec tm1,tm2;
 tm1.tv_sec = seconds;
 tm2.tv_nsec = nanoseconds;
 nanosleep(&tm1,&tm2);
```

This is my signal handler

```
static void speed_handler(int signal)                                          
{                                                                              
    long max_nano = 1000000000L;                                               
    long incrementer = 250000000L;                                             
    if(speed_control == 0)                                                     
    {                                                                          
        if(nanoseconds == 0L && seconds > 0)                                   
        {                                                                      
            seconds -= 1;                                                      
            nanoseconds = max_nano;                                            
        }                                                                      

        if(nanoseconds != 0L)                                                  
            nanoseconds -= incrementer;                                          
    }                                                                          

    if(speed_control == 1)                                                     
    {                                                                          
        nanoseconds += incrementer;                                            
        if(nanoseconds >= max_nano)                                            
        {                                                                      
            nanoseconds = 0L;                                                  
            seconds += 1;                                                      
        }                                                                      
    }                                                                          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called IPC, short for Inter-process Communication and there are many ways to do what you want.
Your approach doesn't work because your processes have distinct address spaces so changing a variable in one has no effect on the other.

A few ways in which you could communicate information from one process to another:

- Share memory between processes (using [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) with `MAP_SHARED`)
- Send extra information using signals (look up [`sigqueue`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigqueue.html) and `sigval`. Or maybe check this old answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7270506)
- Use a [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
- Or a [message queue](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_open.html)

There are quite a few more mechanisms but this should get you started.

Comment: So i modified the code to what it actually suppose to do. Just create a child and use execl. We are apparently only suppose to be using signals for this which just doesnt make sense to me. Sigqueue looked like it wouldve been nice but apparently its not supported on mac sierra

Comment: Okay so what I did to fix my issue is I put the signal handler in the process that was printing out the text on the other terminal and then used my parent process to send signals to it, and I used two signals for increasing speed and decreasing speed.

Comment: @WizKiz One problem with "classical" signals is that one isn't sure whether the target process receives the signal (and one isn't sure what happens if the signal is sent multiple times in rapid succession).